# Color gradient in 3D graph pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, gradient

I am trying to make a graph from the values that I got from the gyroscope mounted on the pendulum connected to the Arduino. I cannot make colormap/gradient work.

Original graph:

[image]

This is the code that I am using:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height=8cm,
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel={x axis},
    ylabel={Time [ms]},
    zlabel={y axis},
    minor x tick num=4,
    minor y tick num=4,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    view={150}{170},
    ]

    \addplot3[color=red, mark=square, mark size=0pt] 
file {x_y_z_2.txt};
 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph of values from gyroscope}
\label{exponential_decay_graph_speed}
\end{figure}
```

with the first 100 values in the `x_y_z_2.txt` being:

```
x   y   z
0.33    0   9.69
0.33    14  9.68
0.35    27  9.67
0.36    41  9.67
0.37    54  9.66
0.37    67  9.62
0.38    81  9.61
0.39    94  9.6
0.39    108 9.56
0.4 121 9.56
0.41    135 9.54
0.41    148 9.55
0.43    162 9.54
0.43    176 9.54
0.43    189 9.54
0.43    202 9.52
0.43    216 9.54
0.43    229 9.52
0.44    243 9.54
0.42    256 9.54
0.42    270 9.56
0.4 283 9.56
0.39    297 9.59
0.38    310 9.6
0.36    323 9.62
0.35    337 9.63
0.32    350 9.64
0.32    364 9.67
0.32    377 9.67
0.31    391 9.71
0.28    404 9.71
0.28    418 9.7
0.27    431 9.7
0.26    444 9.71
0.24    458 9.71
0.22    471 9.72
0.21    485 9.7
0.18    498 9.7
0.17    512 9.7
0.17    525 9.69
0.17    539 9.68
0.13    552 9.67
0.15    566 9.64
0.14    579 9.63
0.14    592 9.61
0.12    606 9.62
0.12    619 9.59
0.11    633 9.58
0.1 646 9.56
0.11    660 9.56
0.11    673 9.56
0.08    687 9.57
0.08    700 9.58
0.08    714 9.55
0.08    727 9.56
0.09    741 9.57
0.07    754 9.57
0.08    768 9.58
0.1 781 9.6
0.11    795 9.61
0.12    808 9.61
0.13    821 9.65
0.15    835 9.64
0.17    848 9.67
0.17    862 9.66
0.2 875 9.7
0.2 889 9.72
0.18    902 9.7
0.19    916 9.71
0.23    929 9.72
0.24    943 9.73
0.26    956 9.72
0.28    969 9.71
0.28    983 9.7
0.3 996 9.68
0.33    1010    9.68
0.35    1023    9.67
0.36    1037    9.67
0.37    1050    9.66
0.37    1064    9.64
0.39    1077    9.63
0.38    1090    9.61
0.38    1104    9.58
0.41    1117    9.57
0.4 1131    9.55
0.41    1144    9.54
0.42    1158    9.53
0.43    1171    9.52
0.42    1185    9.52
0.42    1198    9.52
0.43    1211    9.53
0.43    1225    9.53
0.45    1239    9.53
0.44    1252    9.54
0.4 1266    9.55
0.4 1279    9.59
0.38    1293    9.6
0.35    1306    9.6
0.34    1320    9.6
```

For some reason, I am also getting error `Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'z' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'z'..`  on the line `file {x_y_z_2.txt};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{tmp.txt}
x   y   z
0.33    0   9.69
0.33    14  9.68
0.35    27  9.67
0.36    41  9.67
0.37    54  9.66
0.37    67  9.62
0.38    81  9.61
0.39    94  9.6
0.39    108 9.56
0.4 121 9.56
0.41    135 9.54
0.41    148 9.55
0.43    162 9.54
0.43    176 9.54
0.43    189 9.54
0.43    202 9.52
0.43    216 9.54
0.43    229 9.52
0.44    243 9.54
0.42    256 9.54
0.42    270 9.56
0.4 283 9.56
0.39    297 9.59
0.38    310 9.6
0.36    323 9.62
0.35    337 9.63
0.32    350 9.64
0.32    364 9.67
0.32    377 9.67
0.31    391 9.71
0.28    404 9.71
0.28    418 9.7
0.27    431 9.7
0.26    444 9.71
0.24    458 9.71
0.22    471 9.72
0.21    485 9.7
0.18    498 9.7
0.17    512 9.7
0.17    525 9.69
0.17    539 9.68
0.13    552 9.67
0.15    566 9.64
0.14    579 9.63
0.14    592 9.61
0.12    606 9.62
0.12    619 9.59
0.11    633 9.58
0.1 646 9.56
0.11    660 9.56
0.11    673 9.56
0.08    687 9.57
0.08    700 9.58
0.08    714 9.55
0.08    727 9.56
0.09    741 9.57
0.07    754 9.57
0.08    768 9.58
0.1 781 9.6
0.11    795 9.61
0.12    808 9.61
0.13    821 9.65
0.15    835 9.64
0.17    848 9.67
0.17    862 9.66
0.2 875 9.7
0.2 889 9.72
0.18    902 9.7
0.19    916 9.71
0.23    929 9.72
0.24    943 9.73
0.26    956 9.72
0.28    969 9.71
0.28    983 9.7
0.3 996 9.68
0.33    1010    9.68
0.35    1023    9.67
0.36    1037    9.67
0.37    1050    9.66
0.37    1064    9.64
0.39    1077    9.63
0.38    1090    9.61
0.38    1104    9.58
0.41    1117    9.57
0.4 1131    9.55
0.41    1144    9.54
0.42    1158    9.53
0.43    1171    9.52
0.42    1185    9.52
0.42    1198    9.52
0.43    1211    9.53
0.43    1225    9.53
0.45    1239    9.53
0.44    1252    9.54
0.4 1266    9.55
0.4 1279    9.59
0.38    1293    9.6
0.35    1306    9.6
0.34    1320    9.6
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={150}{170},
width=\textwidth, height=8cm,
axis lines=left,
xlabel={x axis}, ylabel={Time [ms]}, zlabel={y axis},
minor x tick num=4, minor y tick num=4,
xmajorgrids=true, ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot3[mesh] table {tmp.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D graph with a color shaded squiggly line]

*Edit:*

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
colormap name=viridis,
view={150}{170},
width=\textwidth, height=8cm,
axis lines=left,
xlabel={x axis}, ylabel={Time [ms]}, zlabel={y axis},
minor x tick num=4, minor y tick num=4,
xmajorgrids=true, ymajorgrids=true,
grid=major,
grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot3[mesh,  point meta=y] table {x_y_z_2.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have few follow up questions. 
Since my final data has 5000+ lines, is there a way to do it in separate file and reference from it instead of directly in code as you did?
Second question would be, is there a way to change the color of the gradient and is there a way to change direction of the gradient (along Time axis for example)?

Comment: A self contained compilable example is always the best format for this site. You can of cause remove `\begin{filecontents*}{tmp.txt} ... \end{filecontents*}` and replace `tmp.txt` with your actual filename. The colors are selected from the color map - add e.g. `colormap name=viridis`  to `axis`. See manual for available color maps and how to create custom. How the colors are selected is controlled by `point meta` add e.g. `point meta=y` to the `\addplot`.